# Mouse-Pointer behaves abnormally

Tags: macos, trackpad, click

**Sometimes**, the pointer(cursor) behaves weirdly, getting clicked here or there, undesired clicks & drags. This has happened around 5-6 times in my MacBook Pro (mid 2012).

What could be the probable cause and how can I work around to remove this behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have an answer that is, "this is your problem and I know what is going on." It's more of an "it sounds like..." answer.

Honestly it *sounds* like there is an external mouse or other USB device which is (for lack of a better word) misbehaving. Which brings up the prime directive of troubleshooting, *Isolate And Identify.*

Unplug **everything** (drives, power, monitors, *everything!*). Do you still have the problem? If not blame something you just unplugged, if the problem still exists then finding the issue becomes more problematic.

**Start in Safe Mode.** Boot the Mac while holding the <kbd>Shift</kbd> Key. You can release the key when you see the Apple logo. Booting will take a longer time. Once you are logged in, does the issue still happen?

1. If not then there is software installed on your Mac that is causing the issue.
2. If so then it is likely/possible it is a hardware issue.

**If it is number 2** (from above) Then you will need to take it into an Apple Store or other Apple hardware tech and see if they can find the issue. In a situation like this it is logical to suspect the trackpad and/or the keyboard. But it is impossible to tell from this side of your screen.

Feel free to edit your original question to the answers to *these* questions and we can help as best we can with more troubleshooting.

Comment: And step 1) should be disabling bluetooth and seeing if someone else has a pointing device which your Mac is seeing as a valid input... cos in a multi-Mac environment in which multiple people used magic mice, I have seen that happen...

Comment: I have a USB headphone (Sims 4 from steelseries) but have installed its driver properly.
Yes, I don't get the issue when it is not connected. Thanks people for the help.